# how to remove the drop down list when user has selected?

Tags: java, php, html

I am working on court booking system. Lets say if a user want to book a court. The system provides a dropdown menu which consist of Court A, Court B and Court C. Assume the first user book court A. Therefore the second user dont see the court A in the dropdown menu selection anymore. How can I do that?

Comment: For how long should Court A be unavailable to other users? Basically, you insert some data to a database, and check against that when creating the dropdown. If there's a match for Court A with the parameters you set, you don't display it in the dropdown.

Comment: Thank you.. I think i got a little bit of that.

Anyway I have 3 courts (Court A, B, C) . When 3 different users book court A, court  B, court C at 8.00pm to 9.00 pm, then the timeslot at 8.00 pm to 9.00 pm will disappear for the fourth user because it has been booked.